# MongoDB examine too many keys on indexed collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance

I'm trying to fetch some records from indexed collection but too many 
keys always examined

here's my query

```
 db.getCollection('transactions').find({"vout.address" : { "$in":['LMUZF47ySkrJ1njBRdQDyPVKkicziiZdQd']} , _id: {$lt: '5e232dec225b5b1c61057ddb'}})
.limit(10).sort({blocknumber: -1 , _id: -1}).hint({ 'vout.address': -1, 'blocknumber': -1, '_id': -1 }).explain();
```

My indexes:

`vout.address_-1_blocknumber_-1__id_-1`

explain returns the following:

```
    { queryPlanner:
   { plannerVersion: 1,
     namespace: 'blockchain.ltc_transactionsTable',
     indexFilterSet: false,
     parsedQuery:
      { '$and':
         [ { 'vout.address': { '$eq': 'LMUZF47ySkrJ1njBRdQDyPVKkicziiZdQd' } },
           { _id:
              { '$lt':
                 ObjectID {
                   _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
                   id:
                    Buffer [Uint8Array] [ 94, 35, 45, 236, 34, 91, 91, 28, 97, 5, 125, 219 ] } } } ] },
     winningPlan:
      { stage: 'LIMIT',
        limitAmount: 10,
        inputStage:
         { stage: 'FETCH',
           inputStage:
            { stage: 'IXSCAN',
              keyPattern: { 'vout.address': -1, blocknumber: -1, _id: -1 },
              indexName: 'vout.address_-1_blocknumber_-1__id_-1',
              isMultiKey: true,
              multiKeyPaths: { 'vout.address': [ 'vout' ], blocknumber: [], _id: [] },
              isUnique: true,
              isSparse: false,
              isPartial: false,
              indexVersion: 2,
              direction: 'forward',
              indexBounds:
               { 'vout.address':
                  [ '["LMUZF47ySkrJ1njBRdQDyPVKkicziiZdQd", "LMUZF47ySkrJ1njBRdQDyPVKkicziiZdQd"]' ],
                 blocknumber: [ '[MaxKey, MinKey]' ],
                 _id:
                  [ '(ObjectId(\'5e232dec225b5b1c61057ddb\'), ObjectId(\'000000000000000000000000\')]' ] } } } },
     rejectedPlans: [] },
  executionStats:
   { executionSuccess: true,
     nReturned: 10,
     executionTimeMillis: 2,
     totalKeysExamined: 911,
     totalDocsExamined: 10,
     executionStages:
      { stage: 'LIMIT',
        nReturned: 10,
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
        works: 912,
        advanced: 10,
        needTime: 901,
        needYield: 0,
        saveState: 7,
        restoreState: 7,
        isEOF: 1,
        limitAmount: 10,
        inputStage:
         { stage: 'FETCH',
           nReturned: 10,
           executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
           works: 911,
           advanced: 10,
           needTime: 901,
           needYield: 0,
           saveState: 7,
           restoreState: 7,
           isEOF: 0,
           docsExamined: 10,
           alreadyHasObj: 0,
           inputStage:
            { stage: 'IXSCAN',
              nReturned: 10,
              executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
              works: 911,
              advanced: 10,
              needTime: 901,
              needYield: 0,
              saveState: 7,
              restoreState: 7,
              isEOF: 0,
              keyPattern: { 'vout.address': -1, blocknumber: -1, _id: -1 },
              indexName: 'vout.address_-1_blocknumber_-1__id_-1',
              isMultiKey: true,
              multiKeyPaths: { 'vout.address': [ 'vout' ], blocknumber: [], _id: [] },
              isUnique: true,
              isSparse: false,
              isPartial: false,
              indexVersion: 2,
              direction: 'forward',
              indexBounds:
               { 'vout.address':
                  [ '["LMUZF47ySkrJ1njBRdQDyPVKkicziiZdQd", "LMUZF47ySkrJ1njBRdQDyPVKkicziiZdQd"]' ],
                 blocknumber: [ '[MaxKey, MinKey]' ],
                 _id:
                  [ '(ObjectId(\'5e232dec225b5b1c61057ddb\'), ObjectId(\'000000000000000000000000\')]' ] },
              keysExamined: 911,
              seeks: 902,
              dupsTested: 10,
              dupsDropped: 0 } } },
     allPlansExecution: [] },
        keyId: Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 1, high_: 1570062499 } } },
  operationTime:
   Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1579375735 } }
```

I'm expecting it to examine only 10 keys but it's examining 911 keys, I noticed that
if I fetch by a different _id the `totalKeysExamined` change depends on _id position, if it's from
the last inserted documents, the number is low and if it's from the first documents the number
is very big

That's an example document from my database

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e206f6f47fafc6b7fa32d0a"),
    "txid" : "33deab70007a4210b2545f1ad516319bdedbcc836faf777c4af27431eab37c6d",
    "size" : 134,
    "vsize" : 134,
    "locktime" : 0,
    "weight" : null,
    "version" : 1,
    "vin" : [ 
        {
            "coinbase" : true
        }
    ],
    "vout" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 50,
            "n" : 0,
            "address" : "LMUZF47ySkrJ1njBRdQDyPVKkicziiZdQd",
            "spent" : false,
            "spent_ids" : []
        }
    ],
    "blocknumber" : 37,
    "time" : 1318474943
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongo's indexes are built in a `b-tree` formation, as explained in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA7ui4l8JBw) video.

We can't really know how the tree has been built but indexed queries are very unlikely to examine just the `x` required documents (as that would require all of those documents to be in the upper tree levels).

You never once mentioned the scale of your collection however examining 900 indexes (or in technical terms iterating over couple of an estimate of 200 tree nodes) does not seem unreasonable.

Your observation of the documents examined based on the `_id` validates that, a certain range will make the tree traverse shorter, hence make mongo inspect less documents. In a really simplified example, imagine we're fetching one document based on `_id` if the documents `_id` is indexed in the `b-tree` root we would inspect a single document and if its in one of its leaf nodes we would inspect more depending on the trees depth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I mentioned, the number differs based on _id number, if my _id is from the first records, all the keys would be examined, which is a big problem. I have more than 2 million documents.

Comment: It's never going to be all the collection due to the limit you added. The `fetch` process will stop once 10 documents were matched, if this is still too slow for you I can't really offer an easy solution, you can experiment with other compound indexes (order of field matters) in hopes they will give better performance. Or consider using a different database or architecture that will better suit your needs

Comment: Actually it's stopped after fetching 10 documents, but the examined keys are too big, is that okay? also, do you think that my index is correct for sort and fetch?

Comment: We are unaware how the actual index tree was built, but as i said examining 1000 keys out of 20 mil sounds very reasonable to me. creating different variations of your index might help with performance, i can't really say if your current index is optimal as it both depends on how your data is distributed for those fields as well as if you use the index for other queries (for example if you query just address at times and you need it index'ed then you can't really move it elsewhere in the compound index)